# Is Eureka running on 8761 or 8080?

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I've created a new spring boot project with "spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server" dependency. Also have added "@EnableEurekaServer" annotation and launched the spring boot app.

I see the below log messages

```
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
```

From above, as I understand. Tomcat is running on port 8080 and eureka server is running on port 8761.

If so,

1. How come the Eureka Dash board is accessible at http://localhost:8080/ ? When the eureka server is running on port 8761 ?
2. On one of the client, I configured the following in the .properties file

   eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

Above, I specified the Eureka server location. But, why is the client unable to register?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default it works on 8761, so configure server.port=8761